# How to send the form data including excel file to the controller in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to send the form data including excel file through fetch. But unable to hit the server using asp.net core.

```
       const formdata = new FormData();
       formdata.append('excel', file);
       formdata.append('name', "importFile");
```

Client Side:

```
    fetch(url, {
                 method: 'POST',
                 body: formdata
         })       
    .then(data => {
        return data;
    });
```

Server Side:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Home/ValidateFile")]
    public ActionResult ValidateFile([FromBody] IFormFile file)
    {

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
        {
            var fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            var parsedContentDisposition = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition);
        }
     }
```

Can you please let me know how to read the excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> send the form data including excel file through fetch. But unable to hit the server using asp.net core.

Please note that applying the [`[FromBody]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#frombody-attribute) to a parameter will populate its properties from the body of an HTTP request, not from posted form fields.

To send file with other data through formdata and read it on server side, you can try to modify the code like below.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Home/ValidateFile")]
public IActionResult ValidateFile([FromForm]FileUploadViewModel file)
{
    //...
    //code logic here
    //...
```

*FileUploadViewModel class*

```
public class FileUploadViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IFormFile excel { get; set; }
}
```

Test Result

[image]